# Dot character in FFMPEG in Python

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg with python3 with filenames like the below:

```
27. Air Space
```

My code is something like this:

```
for folder, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        fullpath = os.path.join(folder, file)
        
        filename = '""' + fullpath + '""'
        actual_filename = fullpath.replace(".mp4","")+".wav"

        os.system('ffmpeg -i {} -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 16000 {}'.format(filename, actual_filename))
```

The problem is FFMPEG cannot find the file and it gives me an error:

```
No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `os.system` use `subprocess` which allows you to pass arguments as a list, with each argument string being a separate list element. Your example turns into

```
import subprocess
for folder, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        fullpath = os.path.join(folder, file)
        
        filename = '""' + fullpath + '""'
        actual_filename = fullpath.replace(".mp4","")+".wav"

        subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', filename, '-acodec', 'pcm_s16le', '-ar', '16000', actual_filename])
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is in `ffmpeg`. I you try to do `cat`, for example, you'll probably get the same error.

It seems like you have to escape spaces and dots in your file name to solve the problem.

You can use `re.escape()` function, but only on the file name, not on the whole path.

For example,

```
import re


def escape_name_in_path(path):
    path = path.split("/")
    path, file_name = path[:-1], path[-1]
    file_name = file_name.split(".")
    
    name, extention = file_name[:-1], file_name[-1]
    escaped_name = re.escape(".".join(name)) + "." + extention
    
    return "/".join(path + [escaped_name])
```

If I execute

```
fullpath = "./27. Air Space.mp4"
os.system("cat {}".format(fullpath))
```

I get error `No such file or directory`.

Now, if I execute

```
os.system("cat {}".format(escape_name_in_path(fullpath)))
```

there's no error and everything works correctly.

Hope that solves your problem!